# R rename files keeping part of original name

Tags: r, wildcard, file-rename

I'm trying to rename all files in a folder (about 7,000 files) files with just a portion of their original name.

The initial fip code is a 4 or 5 digit code that identifies counties, and is different for every file in the folder. The rest of the name in the original files is the state_county_lat_lon of every file.

For example:

Original name:

"5081_Illinois_Jefferson_-88.9255_38.3024_-88.75_38.25.wth"
"7083_Illinois_Jersey_-90.3424_39.0953_-90.25_39.25.wth"
"11085_Illinois_Jo_Daviess_-90.196_42.3686_-90.25_42.25.wth"
"13087_Illinois_Johnson_-88.8788_37.4559_-88.75_37.25.wth"
"17089_Illinois_Kane_-88.4342_41.9418_-88.25_41.75.wth"

And I need it to rename with just the initial code (fips):

"5081.wth"
"7083.wth"
"11085.wth"
"13087.wth"
"17089.wth"

I've tried by using the list.files and file.rename functions, but I do not know how to identify the code name out of he full name. Some kind of a "wildcard" could work, but don't know how to apply those properly because they all have the same pattern but differ in content.

This is what I've tried this far:

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxx")
Files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/xxx", pattern = "fips_*.wth" all.files = TRUE)
newName <- paste("fips",".wth", sep = "")

for (x in length(Files)) {
  file.rename(nFiles,newName)}
```

I've also tried with the "sub" function as follows:

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxxx")
Files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/xxxx", all.files = TRUE)
for (x in length(Files)) {
  sub("_*", ".wth", Files)}
```

but get Error in as.character(x) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

OR

```
setwd("C:/Users/xxxx")
Files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/xxxx", all.files = TRUE)
for (x in length(Files)) {
  sub("^(\\d+)_.*", "\\1.wth", file)}
```

Which runs without errors but does nothing to the names in the file.

I could use any help.
Thanks

Comment: Not `for (x in length(Files)` but `for(x in 1:length(Files))`. Maybe `for(x in 1:length(Files)) {file.rename(Files[x], newName[x])}` works.

Comment: you're right, thanks! I corrected that part of the code, but still not working. There's probably something else I'm doing wrong

Comment: I noticed `file.rename` can take vectors as arguments. So `file.rename(Files, newName)` would give what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example.

Preparation for data to use;

```
dir.create("test_dir")

data_sets <- c("5081_Illinois_Jefferson_-88.9255_38.3024_-88.75_38.25.wth",
  "7083_Illinois_Jersey_-90.3424_39.0953_-90.25_39.25.wth",
  "11085_Illinois_Jo_Daviess_-90.196_42.3686_-90.25_42.25.wth",
  "13087_Illinois_Johnson_-88.8788_37.4559_-88.75_37.25.wth",
  "17089_Illinois_Kane_-88.4342_41.9418_-88.25_41.75.wth")

setwd("test_dir")
file.create(data_sets)
```

Rename the files;

```
Files <- list.files(all.files = TRUE, pattern = ".wth")
newName <- sub("^(\\d+)_.*", "\\1.wth", Files)

file.rename(Files, newName)
```

Comment: Thank you cuttllefish44. Sorry for the bugging, just started working with programming. Why do I need to create a new directory and file? Thought the list.files function was already doing that automatically. When I run the code, I get TRUE TRUE TRUE...  for each file in the folder but does nothing to files' name. Must be doing something worng but don't know what.

Comment: @EBB; Sorry for not explaining enough. It isn't necessary for you to do the first part, but I need it because I don't files and directory. The first part being to make this QA reproducible. And I don't know how to suppress the announcements of success/failure. This code makes files having the same name as yours in test_dir and renames it, at least in my env.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, it really helps. Still trying to make mine work: it flags TRUE or FALSE, and when FALSE erases files from the directory.

Comment: Now it's substituting the initial fips code with fip.wth as I wanted BUT keeps the rest of the string. Getting closer though.

Comment: I was missing a "." in the regex. Thanks @cuttlefish44, it works!